# Why XML is meant to be Software and Hardware independent?

Tags: xml, software, hardware, portability

While studying the features of XML, I got to know that XML is software and hardware independent. Can anyone explain me why it is meant like that?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I searched it on [Google](https://www.google.co.in/#q=why+xml+is+software+and+hardware+independent&spell=1) and found some answers, I understood about Software independent but I couldn't understood about the term Hardware independent. That's why asked a question here. Sorry if my question is not fit here.

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Hardware independent means it can be handled the same way even in different kinds of computer architectures. For example, XML isn't affected by [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @SathiyaKumar Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hardware independent means it can be handled the same way even in different kinds of computer architectures. For example, XML isn't affected by [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess).

Answer (score 3):

Historically, the "normal" way to save structured data was to simply write the in-memory data to disk.

However this caused several issues.

1. It closely coupled the storage format to the internal data structures of the application. This was problematic for interoperability and also from a maintinance and security point of view.
2. The layout of data in memory would depend not only on the data structure definitions provided by the programmer, but also on the hardware and the toolchain. If you built the same software for a system with different endianness, different floating point format, different structure packing, or different sizes of the basic C data types then unless special precautions were taken the software may save data in an incompatble format.
3. The data was not in any way self-documenting. Someone facing a file of data from an unknown application would have to perform significant reverse engineering effort to determine what it meant.

In general when the specificatoin of a language did not nail something down, implementors did whatever they felt fit best with the target hardware. So even with the same operating system and the same compiler toolchain if the target architecture was different the implmentation defined parts of the programming languages was also likey to be different.